# Response is not successful when trying to post using retrofit

Tags: android, json, web-services, retrofit

I'm trying to post data to http://biokod.net:8990/api/users/ using retrofit but im not getting successful response.

Example of json request:-

```
   {"params": {"password": 
"8d969eef6ecad3c29a3a629280e686cf0c3f5d5a86aff3ca12020c923adc6c92", "email": 
"jkowalski@test.pl"}, "method": "login", "id": "12345", "jsonrpc": "2.0"}
```

Example of successful response:-

```
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': '12345', 'result': {'roles': [0], 'token': 
'VDKlZYXucIWdhvnbgFEPitkN', 'uid': 1}}
```

User model:-

```
public class User {

    private Params params;

    private String method;

    private String id;

    private String jsonrpc;

    public Params getParams() {
        return params;
    }

    public void setParams(Params params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    public String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }

    public void setMethod(String method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getJsonrpc() {
        return jsonrpc;
    }

    public void setJsonrpc(String jsonrpc) {
        this.jsonrpc = jsonrpc;
    }
}
```

Params model:

```
public class Params {

    private String password;

    private String email;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public interface UserClient {
    @POST("user")
    Call<User> login(@Body User user);
}
```

Then on button click i create User object and send it as parameter to sendNetworkRequest method

```
Params params = new Params();
params.setEmail("jkowalski@test.pl");
params.setPassword("8d969eef6ecad3c29a3a629280e686cf0c3f5d5a86aff3ca12020c923adc6c92");
User user = new User();
user.setParams(params);
user.setMethod("login");
user.setId("12345");
user.setJsonrpc("2.0");

sendNetworkRequest(user);
```

However when i check if response is successful i'm getting false

```
private void sendNetworkRequest(User user){
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://biokod.net:8990/api/users/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        UserClient client = retrofit.create(UserClient.class);
        Call<User> call = client.login(user);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                    Log.d("testtest", response.body().toString());
                else
                    Log.d("testtest", "fail");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Can't figure out what i'm doing wrong, any help appreciated.

Comment: is there any error you are getting in logcat>

Comment: Your base url: http://biokod.net:8990/api/users/ and you use that endpoint as: user . Is your url is correct?

Comment: check your url and keys

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in logcat, when i changed url to  biokod.net:8990/api/ and replaced @POST("user") with @POST("users"), I'm getting susccessful response however response.body.toString() returns com.witanowski.biokod.data.model.User@9057d22 instead of correct json

Comment: try to override toString method in User model.

Comment: To see the error thrown by retrofit, add `t.printStackTrace();` in `onFailure()` method from `enqueue` call.

Comment: your response.body() returns a User class instance. you don't need to parse it, just use it right away. Server response in parsed automatically with Gson in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Satan Pandeya's comment i figured out that i had wrong endpoint and url, the correct url should be  biokod.net:8990/api and endpoint users. Thank you for help.